# Problem converting WriteOutput to usable CFOutput Variables

Tags: cfml, coldfusion-2016

I am pretty sure I have done something similar before when creating dynamic reports, but this has had me stumped.  I have a set of variable names that are being dynamically created, so I am performing a WriteOutput nested within a cfoutput

```
<cfoutput query="GetData">
<cfscript>
    writeoutput(#variabnas#);
</cfscript>
</cfoutput>
```

But all this does is repeats the variable names for the number of records returned by the query, rather than the data.

```
#FieldValue1# #FieldValue2# #FieldValue1# #FieldValue2# #FieldValue1# #FieldValue2#
```

Do I need to wrap the WriteOut in anything else to identify it as an actual variable?  Any help gratefully received, as I don't support CF that often.

Comment: Hi Jeremy! Is the `variabnas` variable a column of the `GetData` query?

Comment: Just a few general notes. First, you are mixing tag syntax with CFScript syntax. In this case it makes sense to stay with tag syntax. Second, you should prepend the scope to the `variabnas` variable to ensure the correct scope and for easier readability. Third, hashes around variables are only required when you're using variables in strings in function calls, so you could just write `writeoutput(variabnas)`.

Answer (score 0):

To get dynamic driven variable names work, I would make use of the evaluate() function. I also wouldn't use cfoutput and writedump with cfscript at the same time. This should work:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop query="GetData">
#evaluate("#variabnas#")#
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

But please use evaluate() with caution because of security and overhead. For further information please read [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-expressions-and-number-signs/dynamic-expressions-and-dynamic-variables.html).

Comment: Thanks Claudio - unfortunately, that doesn't appear to work.  It throws a 500 error with the #evaluate("#variabnas#")# and just displays as before with the #'s removed #evaluate("variabnas")#.   But your answer is definitely on the right track, so many thanks

Comment: I have done this before, and I am pretty sure it works that way. Is it possible the evaluate() function is not allowed in your environment? What does the exact error from the application-log say?

Comment: The problem with using the Evaluate() was because the string had more than one variable name i.e. #FieldValue1# #FieldValue2#  - it works perfectly with a single variable name, so I just need to break them out.  Many thanks.